# Test Multiple Instance in a single PeekPoker Test

Tags: chisel

While Testing the DUT, we pass the DUT as Argument to Test as :

```
class MAIN_TEST(c:inst1) extends PeekPokerTester(c){....}
Object Main extends App {
iotesters.Driver.execute(args,()=> new inst1()){
   c=> new MAIN_TEST (c)
}
}
```

Is that Possible to pass multiple instance to tester.

```
class Main_Test(c:inst1,d:inst2) extends PeekPokerTester(c,d){...}
```

Comment: What my attention is that I want to take the input from inst2 and use inst2. However i dont want to create arbitrary module

Answer (score 0):

The current answer is almost: There is a different tester methodology in chisel3.iotesters.experimental that would allow you to write something like this

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.iotesters.experimental._

class PlusN(n: Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Input(UInt(16.W))
    val o1 = Output(UInt(16.W))
  })

  io.o1 := io.in + n.U
}

class ChickSpec extends FlatSpec with PokeTester {
  test(new PlusN(3)) { (t, c) =>

    test(new PlusN(4)) { (tt, cc) =>

      t.poke(c.io.in, 4)
      val o1 = t.peek(c.io.o1)  // This is unsupported at the moment.
      tt.poke(c.io.in, 3)
      tt.expect(c.io.o1, o1)
    }
  }
}
```

Is this what you have in mind? If so it is possible to get branch that does this. A new generation of chisel testing technology is being developed which should make this easier.